# WP_List_Table error on WordPress 4.4

Tags: table

I've read the thread here : [Fatal error after 4.4 upgrade class-wp-list-table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211647/fatal-error-after-4-4-upgrade-class-wp-list-table)

He was experiencing same problem with me, WordPress won't shows its native table. But unfortunately the given solution in the thread is not working for me.

Methods in WP_List_Table class are still invoking methods from WP_Screen class using $screen property. Unfortunately, the $screen property is not an instance of WP_Screen.

I echoed var_dump version of $screen and prove that the $screen property is not an object, it's a NULL property.

I've also followed this similar conversation in github : https://github.com/ingenesis/shopp/issues/3410

and a branch :

https://github.com/ingenesis/shopp/commit/10f0d112aea5de7b308505d5ffd1c9472818c1ef

But the problem still occurs.

How can I solve that table problem with those new classes in WordPress 4.4?

Thanks.

Comment: Delete your question

Answer (score 1):

Heyaa...,

I've found a final answer, hufft...

Yeah, first I include the necessary classes just like in this thread :
[Fatal error after 4.4 upgrade class-wp-list-table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211647/fatal-error-after-4-4-upgrade-class-wp-list-table)

And second, I added up this line in the display_tablenav method in WP_List_Table class :

```
$this->screen = get_current_screen();
```

before this line :

```
$this->pagination( $which );
```

That added line create a WP_Screen instance for WP_List_Table's $screen. Well, the secret sauce is at WP's get_current_screen() function.

Thanks all.